# Notifying user before overwrite by Copy tool of target with same name in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, copy

At ArcGIS Desktop (advanced) 10.3.1, I've created a model that simply copies a file geodatabase.  Both the source and target locations are parameterized.  Here's a screen shots of the model:

[image]

And here it is in action:

[image]

Here's my problem: the tool overwrites any pre-existing .gdbs with the same name in the target path.  I want to modify the tool so that it notifies the user prior to overwriting.  How can this be done?  Nothing in the Copy tool instructions or environment settings solves the problem.

Comment: In Geoprocessing Options, is `Overwrite the outputs of geoprocessing operations` enabled?

Comment: How have you defined your output parameter?  When I try it I either get an error telling me it already exists and I can't overwrite it, or a warning telling me if I proceed the existing gdb will be overwritten (based on the setting @Paul mentions above).

Comment: If you aren't scared of python you can use the tool validator http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000000t000000 with arcpy.Exists http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000069000000 the tricky part is issuing a message at that time... you will need to use either PyWin32, QT or similar to issue a message box, both of these are 3rd party and may not necessarily be installed on every workstation that intends to use the tool.

Comment: Unchecking Geoprocessing options > Overwrite the outputs... solves my problem!  I'm not a Python expert, but will look into that by converting my model to Python.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in Geoprocessing Options where you can choose whether to *Overwrite the outputs of geoprocessing operations* or not.

[image]

If I uncheck this option, I get an error when I try to run my tool telling me the output already exists

[image]

And if I check the option, I get a warning notifying me that the output already exists, but will overwrite if I click OK to run the model.

[image]

If you are not seeing this warning/error when you populate your `MY_NEW_PROJECT` parameter, it may be because your cursor is still in the field.  <kbd>Tab</kbd> or click out of the field to see if that warning appears.